# GWT textbox KeyPressHandler issue

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am using gwt 2.3 with uibinder.
In this I used a text box, On which I want to add keypress haldler.
Here below is my code. for ui.xml

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:AbsolutePanel ui:field="absolutePanel">
        <g:HorizontalPanel>
            <g:TextBox ui:field="searchTB" ></g:TextBox>

        </g:HorizontalPanel>

    </g:AbsolutePanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

for .java

@UiField
    TextBox searchTB;

```
@Inject
public LibraryFormView(final Binder binder) {
    widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);


    searchTB.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

while running application & loading this page it is giving error like below.

```
[DEBUG] [v4workflow] - Rebinding com.nextenders.client.view.workflow.LibraryFormView.Binder
[DEBUG] [v4workflow] - Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
    [ERROR] [v4workflow] - Method 'onKeyPress' must have a single event parameter defined.
```

I am not getting at what place I am wrong.
Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a method named `onKeyPress` in `LibraryFormView` that is erroneously annotated with `@UiHandler`.

See http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=%22must+have+a+single+event+parameter+defined%22+package:http://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com (it's in a loop over `getUiHandlers`)